# Submit Fields In Table Row Using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I would like to create a object using the row fields(id,title,body) and send using XMLHttpRequest.

See my javascript below.

```
function callAjax(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.send(); //send row (including id(hidden), title(text), body(text)
}

function updated(text) {
    alert(111111111);
}

function deleted(text) {
    alert(111111111);
}
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/9j7ch3ct](http://jsfiddle.net/9j7ch3ct/3/)

I would usually use $(this).closest('tr').find('#id'), but I don't have the jQuery option unfortunately.

Thanks.

Comment: send the post data like this  xmlhttp.send(data); data is a string like this id=val1&name=val2....

Comment: for getting trs use document.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

send the post data like this `xmlhttp.send(data);` data is a string like this `id=val1&title=val2....`

for getting trs use `document.getElementsByTagName` loop the array and frame the data send it with `send(data)` function

Comment: How would I find the elements from the corresponding update/delete row. I have updated the jsfiddle to give you a better idea. Thanks.